# How to set java security policy in tomcat of a web application giving platform to run codes of different languages

Tags: java, tomcat, policy

In my web application I am providing platform to run external codes which will be stored in a particular location say "C:\Users\test".

I want to deny permission for `System.getProperty("user.home")` to read and write and not be able to make any http connection through the codes. How to achieve this?

I also have another question related to it , that is, as we all know that we cannot deny permissions from policy text file , so can anyone let me know what are the permissions given when we mention `permission java.security.AllPermission;` in policy file?

Answer (score 2):

Default security policy is contained in `catalina.policy` file in Tomcat's configuration directory. To apply this file you should run Tomcat with `-security` option. More information is given in Tomcat's [Security Manager HOW-TO](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/security-manager-howto.html)

`permission java.security.AllPermission` grants permissions to do anything. It should be applied only to completely trusted code, e.g. system or Tomcat's libraries. This is the case for the default `catalina.policy`.

Comment: Please check my question. I am asking how to deny permissions @kgeorgiy

Comment: There is no permission revocation mechanics in [.policy files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html). To "deny" something you should not give your permission to do this.

Comment: can you tell the list of permissions given to the user while using permission java.security.AllPermission command ?

Comment: There is no closed list of all possible permissions. For example, there is a separate `FilePermission` for each file. Even the list of permission _types_ granted by `AllPermissions` depends on the version of Java Platform, e.g. `URLPermission` was added only in Java 8.

Comment: So if I want to remove the permission of reading a particular property of System(such as user.home) and I want to keep other permissions as granted by permission java.security.AllPermission.

Comment: There is no way to do this. You should grant `PropertyPermission` to really used properties instead.

Comment: Do you know about pro-grade library and how to use it? as there is a way to deny permissions also @kgeorgiy